# How to make wine use more than 1 CPU core?

Tags: wine, 17.04

Wine uses only 1 of my CPU cores (8 in total) and that is slowing down the application I try to run (a launcher that throttles download speed because of that)

I dont know if wine should use multiple cores normally but on my PC wine uses 1 core.. dont know if that helps but when I open wine's task-manager with `wine taskmgr` I get this on performance:

[image]

Or in other words it doesn't show any RAM/CPU activity (while I am running the launcher and htop shows that wine (actually a command related to what the launcher does) uses 100% CPU

[image]

`/dev/sdb` is the drive that the launcher installs the games and downloads the content to.

Ubuntu version is 17.04 64bit

kernel version is 4.10.0-37-generic

Wine version is 2.0.2

Comment: What version of Ubuntu, and what version of Wine are you using?  Those answers will be very helpful in sorting this out.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Thanks for the heads up, I edited my post 
Ubuntu version is 17.04 64bit
kernel version is 4.10.0-37-generic
Wine version is 2.0.2

Comment: This is a known wine issue and here is a discussion about it with some possible workarounds: https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=19354 and is unrelated to Ubuntu.

Comment: @jpezz nice to know that, but I am not sure if it directly applies in my case, since the launcher (at least I assume) is a normal executable window that doesn't use d9d or 3d graphics in general and also shouldn't wine's taskmanager show something on the "performance" tab?

Comment: @papajo, I believe your problem is a wine issue and that link appears to me to say the same thing. Wine does not use more than one core. I suggest you ask the Wine team how to verify that.